# Need to access embedded div element rendered on ag-grid

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I have implemented an ag-grid , in which one of the columns renders a HTML dropdown.

I need to access the row with the value of the **selected** dropdown value in my angular **controller**.
I cannot find a way to get the value of the selected dropdown from my controller.

Using selectRenderedRows() gives all the rows with **all** the dropdown elements.

Using cellRenderer to populate the dropdown(It is in a div element with a unique select id)

Using : Angular 1.5 (Restrictons on using angular 2+).

Tried various option but not able to get the html element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
  data: 'data',
  selectedItems: $scope.selections,
  multiSelect: true,
  afterSelectionChange: function () {
    //Access $scope.selections here.
  }
};
```

Set grid options. an event 'afterSelectionChange' will be called when you change a dropdown value. Get the specific value from there.

Comment: Thanks Bharat, but it doesnt seem to work. I have multiple rows with 3 dropdowns in each row and depending on the selection will create objects for each row and hit a webservice. Not able to get the selection per row.

Comment: Why can't you implement afterSelectionChange event? Are you not able to se the gridOptions?

Comment: Our company is using a weird wrapper on top so its not direct to use gridoptions.. I got the elements selected through jquery and created the objects. But the afterSelectionChange helped me do some other stuff.Thank you